# Why were my comments deleted on the Ninja identification (Pixels) question?

Tags: support, comments

I'm 99% sure I had at least one if not two additional comments on this question:

[What video game are these ninjas from?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229860/what-video-game-are-these-ninjas-from)

I'm pretty sure there was nothing wrong with them. If I remember correctly, one was pointing out that the OP did have "permission" from another user to post the question on Arqade.

The other comment (or possibly continuation of the first) was a general comment stating I was unsure of the Arqade rules about cross-posting.

I'm not certain why either of these comments would have been problematic, particularly as there are other similar comments still on the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, that was entirely my error - I was attempting to clean up comments on the question, and it looks like while modding from my phone, I deleted some comments like yours that should have stayed. I will rectify that.